# Не проходят CRUD операции

Tags: yii2, crud

Всем доброго времени суток. Имеется на стороне сервера установленный yii2 с конфигурацией:

web.php

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
                'controller' => 'my',
            ]

            ],
        ],
],
```

MyController.php

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return 
    \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(parent::behaviors(), [
        'corsFilter' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
        ],
    ]);
}
```

Ну и модуль Todo.php

```
class Todo extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'list';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['mission', 'date'], 'required'],
        [['mission'], 'string'],
        [['date'], 'safe'],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'mission' => 'Mission',
        'date' => 'Date',
    ];
}
```

В общем обычное серверное приложение для отдачи json списка таблицы из БД.
Через PostMan операция GET отдает как положено json файл, но следующие операции DELETE, POST etc. не проходят, отдает ошибку 405 (Method not Allowed).

Конфигурация:
дистрибутив на основе убунуту
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

php PHP 7.0.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )

В файл apache2.conf добавил строку (Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*") между всеми тегами Directory. Но CRUD операции все так же недоступны. У знакомого, точно такой же код на бекенде, CRUD операции проходят без проблем, правда использует Fedora.Какие либо строки в httpd.conf не добавлял. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Добрый вечер.

Версия операционной системы не имеет к проблеме никакого отношения.

Вам надо разрешить методы для разных действий при помощи [yii\filters\VerbFilter](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-verbfilter)

Если Ваш контроллер наследуется от [yii\rest\Controller](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rest-controller), то возможно Вам поможет переопределение метода [verbs()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rest-activecontroller#verbs()-detail)

```
protected function verbs()
{
  return [
    'index' => ['GET', 'HEAD'],
    'view' => ['GET', 'HEAD'],
    'create' => ['POST'],
    'update' => ['PUT', 'PATCH'],
    'delete' => ['DELETE'],
  ];
}
```

Так же надо в настройках urlManager немного подредактировать правила, например так:

```
'POST delete' => 'my/delete',
```

Соответственно надо удалить код, который Вы добавили до этого в поведение.

Comment: Добавив строчку 'verbs'=>[
                'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    '*'=>['GET','POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
                ],
            ], Ничего не изменило

Comment: Куда добавили строчку?

Comment: Ссылка на скриншот, http://ipev.ru/image/OIG

Comment: Контроллер от какого класса наследуется?